# Mockito method and if test

Tags: java, mockito

I have a problem with the tests Mockito. 
I admit that I do not understand Mockito. 
I read a lot of pages, I read a lot of examples and still nothing.

I have a program in Maven. I define the file name. Displays the contents of the file. 
The program is: App( condition and display of ), methodApp( methods ).

App

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    new App();
}
private App() throws IOException {
    methodApp ViewProgram = new methodApp();
    if (ViewProgram.file == null) {
        out.println("No File!");
        return;
    }
    out.println(ViewProgram.removeSpacesDisplaysContents());
}
```

methodApp

```
InputStream file = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/"+enterNameFileConsole());

private String enterNameFileConsole(){
    out.println("Enter filename:");
    try {
        return new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in)).readLine();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        out.println("Error reading file!");
    }
    return enterNameFileConsole();
}

String removeSpacesDisplaysContents() {
    try {
        return deleteWhitespace(new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(file)).readLine());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        out.println("Error reading file!");
    }
    return removeSpacesDisplaysContents();
}
```

I have to test App(), enterNameFileConsole() and removeSpacesDisplaysContents().

How to test the methods and the condition using Mockito if somebody could present and explain or an idea.

Please help and sorry if the topic is repeated.

Comment: You have an infinite recursive loop in your program because the method `removeSpacesDisplaysContents` calls itself in an infinite recursive loop in the statement `return removeSpacesDisplaysContents();`.

Comment: I tried to change it but then I have a problem with Input Stream, does not give me the name of the file to the stores paths, when instead return I use try ... cry.

Comment: You should probably first concentrate on learning the basics of programming in Java, make sure you thoroughly understand how classes and methods work, before you take on something more complicated such as Mockito.

Comment: I don't agree entirely. Ziomell's code is very unconventional, and indeed has a possible infinite loop in it, but to me it demonstrates understanding. Maybe OP is self-taught? Anyway, I am trying to answer the question without refactoring the original code more than necessary. That's quite a challenge for me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interactions with the file system or command line are hard to test directly. I usually extract them into a separate class or method and stub that class/method's behavior for testing.

For example:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintStream;

public class App {

    private PrintStream out;
    private InputReader inputReader;

    public App() {
        this(System.out, new InputReader());
    }

    // constructor injection used by tests
    public App(PrintStream out, InputReader inputReader) {
        this.out = out;
        this.inputReader = inputReader;
    }

    public void execute() throws IOException {
        if (inputReader.determineFile()) {
            out.println(inputReader.removeSpacesDisplaysContents());
        } else {
            out.println("No File!");
        }
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        App siema = new App();
        siema.execute();
    }

}
```

and:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

import static java.lang.System.out;

public class InputReader {

    private InputStream in;
    private InputStream file;

    public InputReader() {
        this(System.in);
    }

    // constructor injection used by tests
    public InputReader(InputStream in) {
        this.in = in;
    }

    public boolean determineFile() {
        out.println("Enter filename:");
        try {
            file = getResource("/" + readLine(in));
            return true;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            out.println("Error determining file!");
            return false;
        }
    }

    public String removeSpacesDisplaysContents() throws IOException {
        return deleteWhitespace(readLine(file));
    }

    private String deleteWhitespace(String input) {
        return input.replaceAll("\\s+", "");
    }

    // to be overridden in tests
    InputStream getResource(String name) throws IOException {
        return getClass().getResourceAsStream(name);
    }

    // to be overridden in tests
    String readLine(InputStream is) throws IOException {
        return new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is)).readLine();
    }

}
```

Test for App:

```
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.runners.MockitoJUnitRunner;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintStream;

import static org.mockito.Mockito.verify;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;

@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class AppTest {

    private App instance;
    @Mock
    private PrintStream out;
    @Mock
    private InputReader inputReader;

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        instance = new App(out, inputReader);
    }

    @Test
    public void testExecute() throws IOException {
        //SETUP
        when(inputReader.determineFile()).thenReturn(true);

        String expectedResult = "test result";
        when(inputReader.removeSpacesDisplaysContents()).thenReturn(expectedResult);

        // CALL
        instance.execute();

        // VERIFY
        verify(out).println(expectedResult);
    }

    @Test
    public void testExecuteCannotDetermineFile() throws IOException {

        // SETUP
        when(inputReader.determineFile()).thenReturn(false);

        // CALL
        instance.execute();

        // VERIFY
        verify(out).println("No File!");
    }
}
```

And a test for InputReader:

```
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.runners.MockitoJUnitRunner;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

import static junit.framework.TestCase.assertFalse;
import static junit.framework.TestCase.assertTrue;
import static org.testng.AssertJUnit.assertEquals;

@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class InputReaderTest {

    @Mock
    private InputStream in;

    @Test
    public void testDetermineFile() {
        // SETUP
        InputReader instance = new InputReader(in) {

            @Override
            InputStream getResource(String name) {
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            String readLine(InputStream is) throws IOException {
                return null;
            }
        };

        // CALL
        boolean result = instance.determineFile();

        // VERIFY
        assertTrue(result);
    }

    @Test
    public void testDetermineFileError() {
        // SETUP
        InputReader instance = new InputReader(in) {

            @Override
            InputStream getResource(String name) throws IOException {
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            String readLine(InputStream is) throws IOException {
                throw new IOException();
            }
        };

        // CALL
        boolean result = instance.determineFile();

        // VERIFY
        assertFalse(result);
    }

    @Test
    public void testRemoveSpacesDisplaysContents() throws IOException {
        // SETUP
        final String line = "test result";
        String expectedResult = "testresult";
        InputReader instance = new InputReader(in) {

            @Override
            InputStream getResource(String name) throws IOException {
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            String readLine(InputStream is) throws IOException {
                return line;
            }
        };

        // CALL
        String result = instance.removeSpacesDisplaysContents();

        // VERIFY
        assertEquals(expectedResult, result);
    }

    // the test succeeds if an IOException is thrown
    @Test(expected = IOException.class)
    public void testRemoveSpacesDisplaysContentsError() throws IOException {
        // SETUP
        InputReader instance = new InputReader(in) {

            @Override
            InputStream getResource(String name) throws IOException {
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            String readLine(InputStream is) throws IOException {
                throw new IOException();
            }
        };

        // CALL
        instance.removeSpacesDisplaysContents();
    }
}
```

Comment: Adriaan Koster of the earlier problem yourself advised. The problem now is that as I give to the correct file name is displays the content, as it will give erroneous displays errors instead of "No File". 
It can be prolem of If?

Comment: I updated the code for the InputReaderTest, there was a mock missing. The problem you are trying to explain happens when running the App, or when running the tests? I might have broken your code, I didn't compile or test it. Please clarify what exactly goes wrong.

Comment: I wrote to you on mail, mail found on the website. I described the problem and joined screenshots. Here I could not describe the problem. Thank you and best regards

Comment: I fixed the code. There were indeed some bugs. The biggest one was that the code in InputReader was adding "/" twice. Also some incorrect braces in tests and missing @RunWith annotations. That's what you get when you type in code outside of an IDE :-D